# Программа "рисования" тормозит ужасно!

Tags: gdi, c++

О гуру c++ подскажите, что могло ускользнуть от моего взгляда из учебников такого, что заставляет эту простйшую программу тормозить.

Суть её - рисование в окошке мышкой. Но томозит просто жутики.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;   
    int i;
     static int  *x=new int[100],*y=new int[100],*x1=new int[100],*y1=new int[100];
    static int lines=1;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x[lines]=LOWORD(lParam);
        y[lines]=HIWORD(lParam);    
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:     
        x1[lines]=LOWORD(lParam);
        y1[lines]=HIWORD(lParam);       
        lines++;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,FALSE);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
        {
            MoveToEx(hdc, x[i],y[i],NULL);
            LineTo(hdc,x1[i],y1[i]);

        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        delete []x;
        delete []x1;
        delete []y;
        delete []y1;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Есть выход за пределы массивов, нужно:  

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)  

lines начинать с нуля:
  
    static int lines = 0;

После 100 кликов значения начнут записываться за пределы массивов.

Comment: Комментируйте по очереди обработчики сообщений и смотрите на скорость работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, подсказки дельные. Но причина оказалась в другом.

```
InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE).
```

Третий параметр стоит FALSE, а надо было TRUE.